# How do I prevent the image in the background from zooming in modal mode?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 4 pictures and a background image and I wrote a modal for each of them. When I click on the image and it opens in modal mode, the background image also zooms in a bit. In chrome dev tools, I see that a new class is added to body called .modal-open and properties and values are added in the css.

```
body.modal-open {
padding-right: 16px;
display: block; }


.modal-open .modal {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto; }
```

[Link to Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/criscrispy/4r3eu8xt/29/)

How do I prevent the image in the background of the body element from zooming in?

Comment: You should probably add another container to the body and set the background image onto that container, not the body itself

Comment: I think this is because of the page scrollbar. if you want do edit you can add exact background size for example like code below

`background-size: calc(100vh - 20px);`

this is just a dirty css trick

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I think the answer from @iamwhitebox works perfectly. I guess implementing the trick with the scroll-bar also makes sense is also ok. I tiny reason not to use it though could its compatibility on different browsers like IE browser versions. [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS

```
.bg-image {
    background-image: url("Pictures/English-lang-background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="bg-image">

</div>
</body>
```

Correct, @iamwhitebox. It solves the problem.